# Why float don't increase

Tags: android

In `AnswerPage.java`:

```
int obko=0;

static float obkohesap=0.0f;
```

I'm increasing `obko` variable on program

```
obkohesap=obko/10;
```

in `ResultPage.java`

```
txtobko.setText(AnswerPage.obkohesap+"");
```

When I run the program, `txtobko`'s text is always 0.0. I'm sure there isn't an error on the `obko` variable.

txtobko.text=0.0 when obko=12

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Just make 10 a float with 10f

Comment: I changed it: obkohesap=(float) (obko/10.0); and its worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
obkohesap = ((float)obko)/10f;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are dividing integers, so result will be integer too. You have to cast one of operands to float in order to get floating point result, just as Budius mentioned.

Comment: I changed it: obkohesap=(float) (obko/10.0); and its working.Thank you so much!